# How to render LaTeX code in an HTML webpage

Tags: latex2html

In website development, I need to read LaTeX code and render it into an HTML webpage, becoming a separate webpage. I'm not sure if there's any way to render LaTeX code into an HTML webpage

Comment: Welcome! `tex4ht` is designed for this. If you want more help, please provide a minimal working example i.e. TeX code for a minimal document you want to convert.

Comment: I can use latex.js for rendering